# International keyboard commas not recognised in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to replace a comma "，" that is different from "," the standard comma in english keyboard. I believe the other comma is from a chinese keyboard. Thus when pasting it into VBA, it only recongises it as a "?".

If I use excel find and replace, it works. But recording it as a macro won't record that effect as record macro reconises it as a standard comma.

Is there any way around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you have no code to show what you have tried before I am unable to test this for you.

But to answer your question, one option would be to create a vba script that references the Unicode characters and replaces them that way.

> ，=  U+FF0C : FULLWIDTH COMMA
>
> , = U+002C : COMMA {decimal separator}

Comment: chrw(65292) and chr(44)

Answer (score 2):

The standard comma is ASCII 44 dec/2C hex. The 'combining comma' is unicode 65292 dec/U0326 hex.

Try,

```
'for a single cell or string var
.cells(2, "A") = replace(.cells(2, "A").value2, chrw(65292), chr(44))

'for worksheet wide replacement
with worksheets("sheet1")
    .cells.replace what:=chrw(65292), replacement:=chr(44), lookat:=xlpart
end with
```